# Choose if I want to open a URL on iPhone with the browser or with my application

Tags: ios, iphone

Why on iPhone, when you click on a link, it sends you directly to the app and doesn't ask you if I want to open it with the browser or with the app? Is it something that comes by default or can it be solved?

On the other hand, on Android, when I click on a link, it asks me which app I want to open it with. as you can see in the image

Thank you for helping me solve my doubt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation of features in a specific app.

Apple provides a "universal link" feature, which basically means:

1. If app is installed, go to app.
2. If app is not installed, use website (via Safari).

If an app does not use this feature, the link will never send you to the app.